# Sign up and onboarding

Tags: signup-signon, onboarding

We have a big project management web app. Before the user can use the app, we have some steps to complete, like:

1 - **Signup** - 6 fields (Name, Email, Password, Job Role, Phone and Captcha)

2 - **Onboarding** - 4 questions to set up the company (Name, Area of Business, Number of employees and Level - which serves to direct the user to a suggested menu configuration)

3 - **Steps** - 4 steps that teaches the user how to create their first structure in the product (Group of Work, Projects, Activities and Invite coworkers)

We're planning to make these three separate steps for the user to start to use the app. We know it's a complex product. I think we can not skip any field, because all are important for projects and sales area.

There is a trial period available for users.

---

The questions

1) Are there any other possibilities for handling such complex products?

2) Would combining steps 1 and 2 be good possibility?

3) Any other ideas?

Comment: Some questions: Native app or web app? What's your business model? Free, Freemium, trial period or pay immediately?

Comment: Web App, Freemium (but users enter in a trial period)

Comment: So I get a new phone and I need to do everything over again? I bet it's not the app which requires this, but the backend.

Comment: Why do you need a captcha?

Comment: @ThomasYates every signup should have a captcha.

Comment: I'm not shure about captcha, we have many examples that don't use.

Comment: @Delioth every signup should refrain from using captcha unless completely necessary. It's the worst thing to hand a user to fill in.

Comment: @ThomasYates Really? Are you using outdated captchas? The newest google-sponsored ones are just a checkbox that may ask you to tick some squares if it gets weird input. And in this day and age of thousands of blind webcrawlers, captchas are completely necessary (yes, it's possible to beat captchas; but it takes considerably more resources from the bot and doesn't take much of your own server's resources).

Comment: @Delioth I guess you've never heard of e-mail verification. Also - I don't see Facebook, Google or SE (to name a few) using a captcha on signup. Do you?

Comment: @ThomasYates Email verification takes much more work for the end-user than a checkbox captcha. (Check box, maybe click 5 more times; vs open new tab, navigate to email, sign-in, click link or copy code). More work for the end user is generally bad, and email verification really only verifies that the email you sent something to belongs to whatever signed up (since most email verification is just a link to follow, or rarely a code to copy-paste). If your crawler can't open an email to follow a link, it's got problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three things:

1. Look at every piece of information you're asking for. What will you do with it? For example, why are you asking for phone number? Will you ever actually call a user? If not, then don't ask for it. What are you doing with number of employees? (These are rhetorical questions. No need to answer them for us. Just think about it.)
2. Ask for information only when you need it. (There's a name for this, but I can't think of it.) For example, don't ask for the user's phone number during registration. Get it just after the user asks you to call them. This shortens the registration/on-boarding process and makes it clear to the user why you're asking for that piece of their information. (Notice how your phone apps don't ask for access to your camera until you try to take a pic for the first time.)
3. Make sure to provide a "skip" option where appropriate (at least on "Steps") so users can jump ahead and just get started. People are signing up for your app for a certain reason and you don't want them to forget why they're there by the time they finish all the training and everything.

Comment: You're right! But the sales operation is based on calls. So when user sign up, we try do call him based on Lead Score (we use number of employees, job role to define priority to call or even not call - e.g. students).

Comment: @ThiagoA.Klein: This site is about **User** experience. The user doesn't want to be called anyway. You're not going to get good data - they'll just enter 1-999-999-9999 or so. Add validation to avoid it, and you'll find users will just quit the signup. Remember, you can get a one-star review in seconds.

Comment: @ThiagoA.Klein, if it's necessary, that's fine. I just see too many forms that ask for info for reasons I can't imagine.

Comment: @KenMohnkern Yeah too much information. Remove any field it's equal do reinvent all the sales process :/

Comment: @KenMohnkern "There's a name for this, but I can't think of it." -> [progressive disclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure)?

Comment: I think thats it, @Silveri.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your three questions in one complete answer so bear with me.

Your sign up and onboarding looks quite long and complex. You have a lot of steps. Be very clear to your users where they are in the process and what you expect from them. Make the steps feel logical and intuitive.

[Check out these great examples about onboarding.](https://www.appcues.com/blog/the-5-best-user-onboarding-experiences/)

A few things to take away from it is to make it fun (Duolingo). First they teach you something and after that they ask you to register. The final step to register is a smaller step if you have something you want. In Duolingo's case; you want to save your progress.

Also be very clear in your labeling. Have clear call-to-action. You can use progress bars to show how far along your users are in the onboarding process. All of these tools will help your sign up and onboarding process feel shorter and easier to complete.